# ELIMINAR UN ELEMENTO DESDE LA POSICIÓN EN JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario que recibe archivos multiples

```
<input id="upload3" name="upload3" type="file" multiple accept=".pdf" style="display: none;" onchange="handlePdfFiles(this.files)">
```

Mi evento handlePdfFiles me recibe los files subidos del formulario y los almaceno en una variable global filesvar

```
var filesvar = ''; function handlePdfFiles(files) {
            filesvar = files;
            console.log("filesvar", filesvar);
```

El resultado haciendo console log es correcto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregutna es como elimino un elemento desde su posición, por ejemplo si quiero eliminar filesvar[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjoOX.png)] en la posición número 1.

He probado con splice(), pero, esto solo sirve para un array, pero no para mi variable filesvar que es un object.

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar una propiedad concreta de un objeto en JavaScript, se puede usar el operador `delete`.

Por ejemplo:

```
delete FileList.1
```

Y así se elimina la propiedad "1" del objeto "FileList".

Aquí se explica mejor cómo usar este operador: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_property_object.asp

Comment: Hola @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza. Lamentablemente no funciona para objetos tipo `[object FileList]`, pero sí funciona para `[object Object]`. Tampoco funciona como `delete FileList.1`. En tal caso, funcionaría como `delete FileList["1"]`, sin embargo, para ese tipo de objetos no.

Comment: Ah, no tuve en cuenta ese detalle. Igual investigué un poco más y encontré esto: [How do I remove a file from the FileList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144419/how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-filelist). Parece que no es posible eliminar solo algunos archivos almacenados en `FileList` ya que es de "solo lectura", pero sí se pueden eliminar todos los archivos como se explica en la respuesta aceptada a esa pregunta.

Comment: Agrégala como observación y así aprovecha para terminar tu respuesta.

Comment: gracias, finalmente lo solucione cambiando de variable, pero, interesante lo del FILELIST.